# add commit button to same fieldset as inputs in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

How do I add my submit button into the same li as the inputs of my form?

```
= semantic_form_for :regression_test_environments do |env|
  %ul.input-list
    = env.inputs :name, :navigation, :url, :title => "New Environment"
    %li.commit= env.submit "Save Environment", :class => "submit"
```

This just puts  the li outside of the fieldset with class inputs. Is there a way to include it in the fieldset(and ul)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
= semantic_form_for :regression_test_environments do |env|
  %ul.input-list
    = env.inputs :name => "New Environment" do
      = env.input :name
      = env.input :navigation, 
      = env.input :url 
      %li.commit= env.submit "Save Environment", :class => "submit"
```

I am not sure if you have a field `:title` or you want to name your fieldset (in which case you need to use `:name`).